# How to manage app crashing when grpc blockingstub is called with deadline

Tags: java, android, grpc, channel

I am trying to develop an app that connects to a backend server using a grpc blocking stub.

I get to the point where the request is being made and my app crashed due to deadline being exceeded. The expected behavior is that the try catch handles when the server is unresponsive as the app crashing and closing is not acceptable.

Below is my stub generation and error:

```
    public LoginDataSource() {
    }

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {
        LoginServiceGrpc.LoginServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = LoginServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(commChannel);
        GrpcServerComm.LoginData loginData = GrpcServerComm.LoginData.newBuilder().setUsername(username).setPassword(password).build();
        GrpcServerComm.LoginRequest serverResponse = blockingStub.withDeadlineAfter(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).getLogin(loginData);
        long serverResponseVal = 0;
        try
        {
            LoggedInUser activeUser = new LoggedInUser(username,username);
            serverResponseVal = serverResponse.getResponseVal();
            return new Result.Success<>(activeUser);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }

    }
```

Debug:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.equinox.openeyes, PID: 2401
    io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 1766623100ns. [buffered_nanos=1774305900, waiting_for_connection]
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:240)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:221)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:140)
        at com.equinox.openeyes.LoginServiceGrpc$LoginServiceBlockingStub.getLogin(LoginServiceGrpc.java:155)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public MutableLiveDataResult<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {

        MutableLiveDataResult<LoggedInUser> observeable = new MutableLiveDataResult<LoggedInUser>();
        LoginServiceGrpc.LoginServiceBlockingStub service = LoginServiceGrpc.newStub(commChannel);
        GrpcServerComm.LoginData loginData = GrpcServerComm.LoginData.newBuilder().setUsername(username).setPassword(password).build();
        service.getLogin(loginData, new StreamObserver<LoggedInUser> {

            public void onNext(LoggedInUser response) {
                observeable.postValue(response);
            }

            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                observeable.postValue(null);
            }

            public void onCompleted(Throwable t) {
                // if you wanna close your channel
                // commChannel.shutdown();
            } 
        })
        return observable;
    }
```

And observe the changes in the `MutableLiveData` and get your result there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wasn't able to use this since I have other activities needing the return type defined.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue is that my blocking stub call needed to be within the try catch.

Once I moved it down there and changed the exception to a StatusRuntimeExceotion, I was able to handle the exception accordingly.